# How can I simulate a mobile device with intern / leadfoot

Tags: google-chrome, intern, leadfoot

I would like to test our mobile site but it is only served if we simulate a User Agent via chrome's device mode. How can I use the [leadfoot API](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/module-leadfoot_Session.html) to simulate a mobile device such as an iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of configuring Intern to run a browser installed locally, you can configure it to run on a service such as BrowserStack (more information on this [here](https://github.com/theintern/intern/blob/master/docs/running.md)) so you can simulate it on mobile browsers.

Once you have that set up, Leadfoot provides specific methods that work well to test touch devices such as 'touchScroll'. Most if not all of the Leadfoot methods will work on simulated mobile devices however so you won't be limited to just the touch screen specific ones.